# LED control from android without using arduino and similar costly boards

Tags: android, arduino, adk, accessory

I want to control an LED from an android application, Can I do it without arduino or similar costly boards, I need only an on/off control from a button in my android app.

Comment: Shouldn't this go in http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You'll need any kind of harware, receiving the signals from your application. The cheapest method might be to use an arduino. However, you have to develop an arduino server, which can be quite difficult.

If you have an old cell phone around, you can use that as a receiver. have a look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tHlJLQvE1Y